# adding url with parameters to tweetinvi

Tags: tweetinvi

I am trying to publish a tweet that includes a url that ends like 
`?r=twitter&lkey=oxvN3E8o3` and it does not work. Tweeter returns  `{"errors":[{"code":32,"message":"Could not authenticate you."}]}`. but if I remove parameters it works. BTW length is not a problem.

Thanks

Comment: Would you be able to share privately the url that you are trying to use? I am on gitter https://gitter.im/linvi/tweetinvi

Comment: I am not on gitter but I can give you this much  http://subdomain.domain.com/public/?r=twitter&lkey=6n6hmT2N

Comment: Thanks, I will get back to you.

Comment: I have just tried : `var tweet = Tweet.PublishTweet("hello subdomain.domain.com/public/?r=twitter&lkey=6n6hmT2N");` and it does work in both 0.9.12.2 and 0.9.13.0.

Comment: Thanks for pointing to the versions. I was using 0.9.10. Now it works for me too with 9.12.

Answer (score 0):

I have been check out to your link that is work correctly . Again you try it but you do not enter hello befor link . Only you enter link in publish function.